# Rabbitmq c#: Should one consumer accept only one type of message or we can send different type of message using NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I read about multiple exchanges in rabbitmq like fanout etc. for multicast, broadcasting messages.

One way to broadcast/multicast could be by having identifiers in the rabbitmq message body itself rather than differentiating it through routing-key/headers etc.

What is the benefit of using routing-key/headers to decide the consumer VS
pushing all data through NameValueCollection and deciding on single consumer, what action is to be taken?

One benefit, I see here is by having one type of object for each consumer, it looks like that each consumer would have just Single Responsibility. Any other compelling thing to opt this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could use MassTransit(http://masstransit-project.com/) to broadcast and consume your messages through Rabbitmq. I think it is a good approach since you are thinking about different contracts/consumers.

I recommend you to take a look at the documentation to see if it is a good fit for your needs.